# Click Event work in "jquery.min.js" but not work with "jquery.mobile.min.js"

Tags: jquery, mobile, click

If I modify the jquery file "jquery.min.js" to "jquery.mobile.min.js"
the Click event not work.
On other pages I will need to use both versions.

JQUERY:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var tag = "";

            $("button#upload").click(function() {
              $("#upload_file").click();
            });

            $("#upload_file").on('change', function() {
              tag = "file";
              var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();
              $('#EmployeeId').val(filename);
            });

            $("#EmployeeId").on('change', function() {
              tag = "text";
            });

            $("#tag").on('click', function() {
              alert(tag);
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

BODY:

```
    <input type="text" id="EmployeeId" value="" />
    <input type="file" id="upload_file" style="display:none" />
    <button id="upload">UpLoader PRO</button>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <button id="tag">TAG view</button>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  They are not the same thing and not interchangeable.  jQuery Mobile is a UI library for mobile devices built _on top_ of jQuery, much like the jQuery UI, and as such is dependent on the base jQuery library to function.

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution:

```
$("#element").bind('click vclick', function(){...}
```

instead of

```
$("#element").on('click', function(){...}
```